# simplest way to throw up disclaimer text after user click on information icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Any advice/suggestions regarding the simplest way to throw up disclaimer text after user click on information icon?  This is for iPhone/iPad development.  Jumping across to a separate XIB/controller might be overkill? (although perhaps it is the simpliest to setup?)

Requirements then would be:

- main screen has a small "info" button in one corner
- clicking on this button should bring up a "modal" view of disclaimer text
- should support scrolling (in case of a lot of text)
- should allow the user to then somehow dismiss and get back to main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I think is to present the text in `UITextView`, which is scrollable, in a custom view controller that you present modally.
You can even store the the text in. Now adding a button to dismiss it, and you are done.

Comment: thanks - do you think it's easier just doing programmatically, to avoid having to create a new XIB/*.m/*.h file?

Comment: to be honest, no I don't think it's easier programmatically, because in IB, you can write many many instructions just by clicking with a mouse